# using Codeigniter and some plugins as framework for commercial software,possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've chosen to use codeigniter as a code base for my project (commercial software)
i've found that i can use the codeigniter in anyway (means i can use it in my commercial software) but there are some controllers and/or models i need to use too like authentications model and the template model ,am i allowed to use them in my commercial software or since it is a commercial software; making a it from scratch is more professional ? another thing; is a template model useful in my case or maybe the integrated template parser in codeigniter is enough to do the task ? there you go, edited to give more sense =]

Comment: for legal/licence advise, ask a lawer. for the rest, your question is much too broad / imprecise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [license agreement](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html) for CI and for the other code you download and use in CI. The license agreement for CI clearly states you may use CI anyway you wan't as long as you maintain and keep the copyright notice.

The template parser is a thing you should answer yourself - we don't know what your needs or level of template parsing you want.

Comment: i found many models and controllers without a license, do they stand for the same agreement(CI's) ?

Comment: I usually contact the persons responsible for the scripts and ask if I have doubts. I'm not familiar with any laws regarding this, but if the author allows downloading his scripts, but no license is provided with his scripts I would assume the use would be unlimited - until something else has been stated from the author. But when in doubt, contact the author and ask.

Comment: ok thank you,i think making things from scratch is more *professional* than using other solutions

Answer (score 1):

hey,
all things which come within the CodeIgniter bundle should be useable even in a commercial software... if you use models/controller etc from third u have to check this individual.
If a template model/engine or whatever is useful in your case belongs to your case which we didnt know :)

hope i could help you a littl bit

greetings